# Cannot create Topic with ARM to Service Bus Namespaces with Geo-Redundant Disaster Recovery

Tags: azure-devops, azure-resource-manager

I have created "Service Bus Namespaces with Geo-Redundant Disaster Recovery", which creates 2 premium namespaces with 1 units each as it should. https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-servicebus-create-namespace-geo-recoveryconfiguration

Then I try to create Topic, but failing. I like to create with own ARM so that any day I can add new Topics. I would like to create several topics here.

This ARM seems to try create new namespace while I would like to use existing namespace created earlier.
https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/101-servicebus-topic

New-AzResourceGroupDeployment : 11.05.49 - Resource Microsoft.ServiceBus/namespaces 'sb-namepace-a' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "message": "SKU change invalid for ServiceBus namespace. Cannot downgrade premium namespace. CorrelationId: 1111f842-1ddf-417a-a302-
829b6445e30c",
    "code": "BadRequest"
  }
}'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the error pretty clearly says - you are trying to change the SKU. add the SKU part back and it should work:

```
"sku": {
    "name": "Premium",
    "tier": "Premium",
    "capacity": 4
},
```